# What does "was" refer to?

Tags: sentence-structure, relative-pronoun

> Das ist es, *was* wir in der Welt ändern müssen.

What does *was* refer to: *das* or *es*? And why?

Comment: I don't get the intention of the question.  *es* is optional and anyway referring to the same as *das*. In writing the sentence would likely boil down to *Das müssen wir in der Welt ändern*. Your sentence sounds like thinking took place while speaking (P. S. Umlauts are not optional in German. )

Comment: What? The buddha himself said it. This is a written sentence. not speech

Comment: I'm somewhat sceptical, whether Buddha wrote German. More context would a benefit for the question anyway.

Comment: Your question boils down to what the object of the main sentence is. I'd say "es".

Comment: @guidot Maybe this clarifies the question for you? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antecedent_(grammar)

Comment: @Roland so this is like, das=the precedin context es=was? es=whhhat we have to change in this world? and es can be omitted right? it is just a placement word right?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an interesting question, because the test of @jonathan.scholbach's and my choice, the *replacement test*, yields opposite results!

In the following, I will use as a replacer *die Langeweile*, simply because @jonathan.scholbach used it, too.

#### Replacing *das*

When I read the question for the first time, I thought to replace *das*. The result is as follows:

> *<s>Das</s> Die Langeweile* ist es, *<s>was</s> die* wir in der Welt ändern müssen.

Conclusion: The relative pronoun *die* refers to *die Langeweile*. By analogy, the relative pronoun *was* should refer to *das*.

#### Replacing *es*

User @jonathan.scholbach chose to replace *es*, and got the following result:

> Das ist *<s>es</s> die Langeweile*, *<s>was</s> die* wir in der Welt ändern müssen.

Conclusion: The relative pronoun *die* refers to *die Langeweile*. By analogy, the relative pronoun *was* should refer to *es*.

#### Bottom line

We get opposite results depending on what is replaced (*das* versus *es*). Therefore, either the replacement test is not appropriate to figure out which is *the one* antecedent of the relative pronoun, or—this is the interpretation that I prefer—*both are* the antecendents of the relative pronoun.

Comment: Note you can replace "es" with **nothing** and still have a valid sentence with the same meaning. "was" still must refer to something, so it's obviously "das"

Comment: @tofro, good point.

Answer (score 1):

Since the given sentence lacks context, which leaves open what *das* refers to, I will use the following example with a noun phrase subject. I use *(es*) to indicate that the sentence is fine with or without *es*. The meaning of the sentence is not affected by its presence or absence.

> Eine gutwillige, achtungsvolle Haltung – das ist (es), was der Anstand von uns fordert. ([Haluschka](http://www.zeno.org/Kulturgeschichte/M/Haluschka,+Helene/Noch+guter+Ton/Untergebener+und+Vorgesetzter))

I propose analysing the clause starting with *was* as a [free relative clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause#Bound_and_free). This is a term from traditional grammar that is a bit misleading in that it suggests that free relative clauses are a special kind of relative clause. However, they behave completely differently.

- Formally, free relative clauses do not have an antecedent and serve as the argument of a verb, for instance as a subject or object clause.
- Semantically, free relative clauses introduce new referents, similar to the way definite noun phrases do.

---

Let's look at some English examples, with the direct object marked in bold.

> 1. He took back **his words**. (noun phrase as object)
> 2. He took back **the words** he said. (with a "regular" relative clause)
> 3. He took back **what he had said**. (free relative clause as object)

Observe how the free relative clause replaces a noun phrase, functions as a direct object and introduces a new referent, i.e. "the things he had said".

Just like German, English allows the sentence in 3. to be modified as follows:

> 4. He took back **that which he had said**.

This sentence is synonymous with 3. It cannot be parallel to 2., as *that* in 4. does not introduce a referent and cannot stand alone:

> *He took back that.

(Note that *he took that back* is obviously grammatical, but completely different: in this instance, *that* refers back to something that has been introduced earlier, which it does not do in 4.)

One can therefore either group 4. with 3., or treat it as a construction *sui generis*. I prefer the former, even if that stands in conflict with the traditional definition of a free relative clause in that the relative pronoun *which* being connected to the pronoun *that*.

---

Now let's move back to German and the modified example sentence.

> Eine gutwillige, achtungsvolle Haltung ist (es), **was der Anstand von uns fordert**.

If *es* is missing, the bolded clause is a free relative clause functioning as the [subject complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_complement) of *sein*.

If *es* is present, it has no referential value: neither does it refer back to anything mentioned previously, nor does it introduce anything new. I suggest thinking of it as a [*Korrelat*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korrelat_(Grammatik)): a word that simply announces that an argument clause is following, in this case a free relative clause.

Using the same analysis on the original sentence

> Das ist (es), was wir in der Welt ändern müssen.

we get the following meaning

> That (which was mentioned previously) has the property of being the thing that we need to change in the world.

with *the thing that* being the meaning contributed by the free relative clause, or specifically the *(es) was*: the introduction of a new referent.

Comment: ", was wir in der Welt ändern müssen" ist **kein** freier Relativsatz. Das erkennt man daran, dass der Satz ("Das ist es") auch ohne den Relativsatz perfekt funktioniert - Er dient deshalb nicht als Subjekt oder Objekt und ist deswegen ein *abhängiger* Relativsatz (von "Das").

Comment: @tofro Ein Beispiel: *(Das) was er sagt, ist falsch und (das) was du sagst, ist es auch*. Hier wäre *es* = falsch und der was-Satz auf *das* bezogen und damit nicht frei (wenn auch aufgrund der Bedeutungslosigkeit von *das* dieses ohne Weiteres weggelassen werden kann und der was-Satz dann wieder frei ist). Ich habe absichtlich ein anderes Beispiel gewählt, in dem der was-Satz sich nicht auf das Subjekt beziehen läßt und vermute, daß der Satz von OP sich parallel verhält. Leider hat OP keinen Kontext angegeben.

Comment: Addendum: Aus dem Argument, daß *das ist es* grammatisch ist, folgt erst einmal nichts. Wie bei allen Proben, die hier schon versucht worden sind, muß natürlich gezeigt werden, daß bei Substituierung oder Weglassung die grammatischen Verhältnisse sich nicht ändern. In *das ist es* ist *es* das Prädikativ, daraus folgt doch nicht, daß es in *das ist (es), was mich stört* auch eins ist.

Comment: Daraus folgt eigentlich nur, dass "Das ist, was mich stört" und "Das ist es, was mich stört" zwar sinngemäß der gleiche Satz sind, aber verschiedene Prädikative haben. Ersteres hat tatsächlich einen freien Relativsatz als Prädikativ, zweiteres nicht.

Comment: @tofro Und was ist das Prädikativ bei zweiterem?

Comment: Genau dasselbe wie in "Das ist es."

Comment: @tofro Wir denken uns einen vorangehenden Satz dazu (wenn *das* das Subjekt sein soll ist das unumgänglich): *Es werden zu wenige geimpft.* Jetzt schließen wir an diesen Satz an: 1) *Das, was mich stört, ist es.* Sinnlos: Wenn tatsächlich ein Relativsatz mit Bezug zum Subjekt vorliegt, kann *es* keine Bedeutung mehr zugeordnet werden. 2) *Das ist (es), was mich stört.* Einfach: *das* = Subjekt = die Tatsache, daß zu wenige geimpft werden und *was mich stört* = Prädikativ.

Comment: Man muß die Semantik miteinbeziehen. Das Verb *sein* benötigt zwei Argumente (grammatisch realisiert als Subjekt und Prädikativ). *Fallschirmspringen ist nicht gefährlich* - *Doch, das ist es.* Hier ist *es*= Fallschirmspringen und *das* = gefährlich. Aber: *Das ist (es), was ich auch immer sage.* Hier *das* = die Aussage, daß Fallschirmspringen gefährlich ist und (*es* =) *was ich auch immer sage* als Prädikativ: "Die Aussage, daß Fallschirmspringen gefährlich ist, hat die Eigenschaft, das zu sein, was ich auch immer sage."

Comment: An deiner Antwort ist viel, wenn auch nicht alles, richtig. Aber die Definition eines freien Relativsatzes ist nunmal - "sie ersetzt ein Satzglied" - die ist hier nicht erfüllt. Semantik hat da nicht viel mit zu tun.

Comment: @tofro Mir fehlt das Argument, warum sich der Relativsatz auf *das* beziehen muß, sobald *es* vorhanden ist. Wenn überhaupt, bezieht er sich auf *es*. Man kann dann gerne sagen: Sobald das Pronomen steht, ist der Satz nicht mehr frei. Aber wozu braucht man dann noch den Begriff **Korrelat**? Paralleles Beispiel: *Ich habe mich (**darüber**) gewundert, **daß du schon wach bist***. Das Korrelat vermittelt optional, der Nebensatz ist in beiden Fällen das Argument.

Comment: Man darf das nicht formal sehen, im Sinne von: Sobald ich ein Pronomen *es* sehe, darf ich den was-Satz nicht als frei bezeichnen. Die Semantik zwischen Relativsätzen und freien Relativsätzen ist grundverschieden: *er bereut die Dinge, die er getan hat* vs. *er bereut (es), was er getan hat*. In letzterem Fall, mit oder ohne *es*, ist es der Nebensatz, der etwas Neues einführt und referentiell einer definiten Nominalphrase entspricht (wie sie im ersten Satz als *die Dinge* auftritt).

Answer (score 0):

We can answer this by making a replacement test:

> Das ist die Langeweile, die wir in der Welt ändern müssen.

Here we can clearly see, that the relative pronoun changes gender in accordance with *Langeweile* and not with *das*, indicating that *Langeweile* is the antecendent of the pronoun.

If we take this back to your sentence, this leads us to say, that grammatically, the antecendent of the relative pronoun in your sentence is *es*. The referents of *das* and *es* however are the same.

---

**EDIT**

But also see the [answer of Björn](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/63249/15393) which proves me wrong by showing that my analysis is simply incomplete.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich You are right. Added a hint to my answer.

Comment: It makes no sentence to replace a free relative clause by a relative clause.

Comment: @DavidVogt I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: Your *replacement test* doesn't make a lot of sense (rather: is invalid). Reson: "es" can simply be omitted from the original sentence without changing anything.

Comment: @tofro Yes. You should downvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note the "es" in your sentence is completely optional and can be omitted without changing the meaning, as in

> Das ist, was wir in der Welt ändern müssen.

In the above, it is obvious that "was" refers to "das" (there's nothing else to refer to). Why should the reference change when something optional ("es") is added?

Comment: What is the subject complement of *sein* if the *was* clause refers to the subject?